# ember-cli ignores my coffeescript test files

Tags: coffeescript, ember-cli

I'm an ember-cli newbie and I'm trying to start testing my dumb app with some dumb tests. It seems that ember-cli ignores any *test.js.coffee files in tests directory.

I'm using version 0.0.44 and installed coffescript adapter with `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-coffeescript`

Any idea why?

Comment: Should your files just have a .coffee extension instead of .js.coffee?

Comment: @Dhaulagiri tried but no way

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the coffeescript module?

```
npm install --save-dev ember-cli-coffeescript
```